# DllImport a file with drv extension

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

I found this statement saying :

```
[ DllImport( "winspool.drv",CharSet=CharSet.Unicode,ExactSpelling=false, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall )]
public static extern long OpenPrinter (string pPrinterName,ref IntPtr phPrinter, int pDefault);
```

I want to know why it didn't import winspool.dll since it is a DLLImport command and what is the difference between winspool.dll and winspool.drv

Comment: Why would you expect it to import a file you have not told it to import? It can not *guess* what you mean when you code the wrong file name.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I don't think that's quite the question being asked - I think it basically boils down to 'Can DLLImport really import more than just DLL files?'

Comment: @AndrasZoltan The OP seems to be confused why DllImport did not load one file (named winspool.dll) when another file (winspool.drv) was specified. I agree that you have the central point of the question answered, but I also wanted to address that the attribute only loads the file you tell it to - it does not try out other files that you haven't named specifically

Comment: @Andras Zoltan exactly , I mean since the file winspool.dll exists why don't we import it instead of winspool.drv

Comment: @Glolita Again: **Why** would you expect it to import a different file than the one you told it to?

Comment: @AndrasZoltan OP's just-posted comment seems to confirm what I thought; he doesn't understand why it loaded the DRV, even though that's the file being specified. OP seems to think some 'magic' would cause it to instead load the DLL file, even though that's not the file indicated in the code.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I sincerely hope you're not right :)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan :-) Unfortunately, a quick scan of recent questions suggests I may be...

Comment: actually I saw in previous posts that some developers uses  [DllImport("GDI32.dll")] and  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] for example so I thought that DllImport works only with dll files (as its name says first and second the examples I found); in the other hand when I found [ DllImport( "winspool.drv")] I said maybe winspool.drv has different fonctioanlities than winspool.dll , and this is where comes my question about the difference between them not as @AndrewBarber said !

Answer (score 2):

A `drv` file is just a dynamic link library (DLL) with a different extension.  There will also be different expectations placed upon it by the OS as to what operations it exposes.

A driver is specifically intended to provide some interface layer between software and hardware, whereas a DLL is just a general purpose module of classes + methods.

Not having written a driver, I wouldn't be able to provide much more clarification than that.

As far as you are concerned, however, it's just a DLL that you can load up and then whose exported methods you can invoke.  If you know the signature, that is.

**Update**

From a bit more research - it's possible that Winspool.drv is actually shelled as a process by Windows.

As for *why* an import has been declared from the `.drv` module and not the `.dll` module, that I ultimately can't answer that categorically since I wasn't around when the code was written!  Ultimately, though, they're not necessarily the same thing and so therefore won't necessarily have the same exports etc.